# Vim searched patterns in middle screen

Tags: vim

Is there any working command / remapping so that when I do

```
:grep *mysearch* *here*
```

the results I iterate with `cnext`, can appear in the middle of the screen directly ?
Ideally I want n to iterate over the results and have the line in the middle screen so I don't have to find where is the cursor in my file each time I see the next results.
I tried many things such as

```
map :<Leader>n :cnext zz<CR>  OR :cnext | :zz | <CR>
```

or any variations but nothing works ...
Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: The quickfix window helps: `:cwindow`.

Comment: You don't get to see the context, the lines before and after your selection.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the technique described [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Replace_a_builtin_command_using_cabbrev), you can do something like this:

```
" Keep quickfix result centered, if possible, when jumping from result to result.
cabbrev <silent> <expr> cn ((getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 3) ? 'cn <bar> normal zz<cr>' : 'cn')
cabbrev <silent> <expr> cnf ((getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 4) ? 'cnf <bar> normal zz<cr>' : 'cnf')
cabbrev <silent> <expr> cp ((getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 3) ? 'cp <bar> normal zz<cr>' : 'cp')
cabbrev <silent> <expr> cpf ((getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdpos() == 4) ? 'cpf <bar> normal zz<cr>' : 'cpf')
```

I originally [had this in my dotfiles](https://github.com/wincent/wincent/commit/7876ef1e442c856079bfb3d6ffc6fbc79a55c265) but have since extracted it into a plugin with a few search-related features called [Ferret](https://github.com/wincent/ferret).

Answer (score 0):

Mappings are not really a good solution for command-line mode; but the main error with your try was some mistakes around `zz`, which is a normal-mode command. It could be:

```
:cmap <Leader>n :cnext<bar>normal zz
```

But `:cabbr` is really better for this case.

An simplified version of wincent's answer is both of these:

```
:cabbr cn cnext<bar>normal zz
:cabbr cn cnext\|normal zz
```

But you *can't* access to the original command by doing this `: cn` (with a space), like with wincent's answer.

Another good way to abbreviate commands : [cmdalias.vim](http://vimawesome.com/plugin/cmdalias-vim), which allows to only recognize abbreviations at start of command-line.